# Sort an array of arrays using group

Tags: javascript, jquery

Consider an array of array with the following values,

```
var myArray = [
                  ["2001-05","Tom","1000"],
                  ["2001-05","Harry","500"],
                  ["2002-06","Harry","3000"],
                  ["2002-06","Tom","2000"],
                   ....
```

The above array is already sorted as per the first element i.e year,
  But I also want the array to be sorted as per the second element according to 
  the year group.

Output be like,

```
      var myArray = [
              ["2001-05","Harry","500"],
              ["2001-05","Tom","1000"],
              ["2002-06","Harry","3000"],
              ["2002-06","Tom","2000"],
               ....
```

Other than using nested loop for sorting can we sort the array as a grouped sorted array in javascript or using jquery.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: No I cant use that library

Comment: @amrendersingh of course it is, why would you need to ask?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```js
var myArray = [
            ["2001-05","Tom","1000"],
            ["2001-05","Harry","500"],
            ["2002-06","Harry","3000"],
            ["2002-06","Tom","2000"]
          ];
var sortedArray = myArray.sort(function (a, b) {  
    return Number(a[0].replace('-','')) - Number(b[0].replace('-','')) || a[1] > b[1];
});

console.log(sortedArray);
```

Comment: Cannot convert first element of array into Number.As the value should be string.For eg. the value can be like "2001-04" instead of "2001"

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```js
var myArray = [
                ["2001","Harry","500"],
                ["2002","Harry","3000"],
                ["2002","Tom","2000"],
                ["2001","Tom","1000"]
              ];
              
var sorted = myArray.sort((a,b) =>{
  if(a[0] !== b[0])
    return a[0] > b[0];
   else if(a[1] !== b[1])
    return a[1] > b[1];
});
console.log(sorted);
```

Comment: I cannot convert the first element into number, As it can be a name of a person or any other string value.

Comment: @swaroopjoseph updated solution based on your comments.

Answer (score 1):

Just use array `sort()`. It will sort the array correctly.

```
var sortedArray = myArray.sort(function(a, b) {  
  return a > b ? 1 : -1;
});
```